# sending email through any account

Tags: php, email, smtp

I need to know something related to "Host". It does only work when sending ID is Gmail ID. I want this to work for any email address (not only for gmail). Kindly guide me what should i change in this code.

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$from = $_POST['email'];                    
$to_id = "myaccount@yahoo.com";
$password = "mypassword";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $from;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', $from);
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', $from);
$mail->addAddress($to_id);
$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->msgHTML($message);

if (!$mail->send()) {
   $error = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    ?><script>alert('<?php echo $error ?>');</script><?php
} 
else {
   echo '<script>alert("Message sent!");</script>';
}
```

Comment: You should change the `Host` to be the SMTP server of the domain that you're trying to send the email from.

Comment: are you referring to, sending to, or sending from?

Comment: sending from...

Comment: not really clear on what you are asking: `$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';` is the mail server your using to send from. you can only use a mail server you have an account on.

Comment: If i have multiple accounts like on yahoo, hotmail etc.. Then how can i set it for any mail server?

Comment: not sure why you would want to, but you can just change the variable as you like, but if you change host you will also need to change: Username, Password; and possible: Port,SMTPSecure

Comment: The free Gmail SMTP server doesn't allow you to send mail from arbitrary addresses. You have to use one of the addresses in your list of aliases in your Gmail settings.